# add headings to rows and columns of matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have 2 matrices and I want to add headings to them. How can I add them and call each cell with the headings of rows and columns of them? And also I have to calculate the sum of each element of rows with the elements of columns. I did it but is there a better way (a loop) to do it instead of what I did? and it returns the headings of rows and columns with the sum (for example: xy:0.022)

Hint: the headings of rows must be different with the headings of columns. 
And I prefer not to use pandas.

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

T = np.array([0,0.012,0.054,0,1,0.03,0.08,0.14,0.02]).reshape(3,3)
#print (T)
#print ('----------------------------')
W = np.array([1,0,0.03,0.01,0.099,0.020,2,0,0.05]).reshape(3,3)
#print (W)

x = T[0][0] + W[0][0]
y = T[0][1] + W[1][0]
z = T[0][2] + W[2][0]
v = T[1][0] + W[0][1]
n = T[1][1] + W[1][1]
m = T[1][2] + W[2][1]
s = T[2][0] + W[0][2]
g = T[2][1] + W[1][2]
k = T[2][2] + W[2][2]
print (x, y, z, v, n, m, s, g, k)
```

Comment: you should try to use pandas dataframe

Comment: I'm beginner in programming

Comment: Do you have an example of heading ?

Comment: Actually I want it for part of speech tagging. (NLP). so the tags are:

Comment: ART, V,N, P for the first matrix

Comment: of course the real matrix is bigger and different from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
>>> import itertools

>>> T = np.array([0,0.012,0.054,0,1,0.03,0.08,0.14,0.02]).reshape(3,3)
>>> T
array([[ 0.   ,  0.012,  0.054],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.03 ],
       [ 0.08 ,  0.14 ,  0.02 ]])
>>> W = np.array([1,0,0.03,0.01,0.099,0.020,2,0,0.05]).reshape(3,3)
>>> W
array([[ 1.   ,  0.   ,  0.03 ],
       [ 0.01 ,  0.099,  0.02 ],
       [ 2.   ,  0.   ,  0.05 ]])

>>> Y = T + W.T  # The additions you do can be expressed like this.
>>> Y
array([[ 1.   ,  0.022,  2.054],
       [ 0.   ,  1.099,  0.03 ],
       [ 0.11 ,  0.16 ,  0.07 ]])

>>> labels = map(lambda x:"".join(x), itertools.product(["x","y","z"], ["a","b","c"]))
>>> labels
['xa', 'xb', 'xc', 'ya', 'yb', 'yc', 'za', 'zb', 'zc']
>>> labels = np.array(labels).reshape((3,3))
>>> labels
array([['xa', 'xb', 'xc'],
       ['ya', 'yb', 'yc'],
       ['za', 'zb', 'zc']],
      dtype='|S2')
>>> for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(Y):
...     print labels[x,y], Y[x,y]
...
xa 1.0
xb 0.022
xc 2.054
ya 0.0
yb 1.099
yc 0.03
za 0.11
zb 0.16
zc 0.07
```

I am not sure on which format you want the headings, but I think this method makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I want the headings of rows be for example: x, y, z

Comment: and headings of columns be for example: a, b,c

Comment: they should be different

Comment: Updated the answer